# setting Custom Account as identity in IIS8

Tags: windows, iis

Am Trying to change the Application Pool Identity to our own custom Account in IIS8. I was succesfully able to do that in one of our windows 2012 servers. But in the other 2012 serverAm getting

`There was error while Performing this operation. Details : Value doesnot fall within the Expected Range`

what would be the reason..i don see anything different in eventviewer as well

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same issue in our setup; same circumstances. Is your server joined to a domain? Did you recently rename the server while joined to the domain?

Comment: Same issue on Windows 10 (upgraded from clean install of Win 7). I never had this issue in Win 7 or 8.